How to pass env variables in spawn when calling from Jest test
One of my Jest tests is spawning a new process to run a server, which will act as a startup test. I want to pass down to the new process the environment variables.
Note: The following test runs on GitLab CI without setting the env variables there, to avoid coupling CI with the test.
What is wrong with the following code?

process.env.HOST = 'localhost';
process.env.DATABASE = 'my_db';
process.env.USERNAME = 'my_admin';
process.env.PASSWORD = 'my_passwd123';


describe('STARTUP: test', () => {
  let app: ChildProcess;
  const url = 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/';

  beforeAll(async () => {
    app = spawn('node', ['index.js']);

    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 8000);
    });
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    app.kill();
  });

  it('should return when calling /health', async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(url);

    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
  });
});



The solution I found:

added in my jest.config.js the the property setupFiles

module.exports = {
  testMatch: ['**/tests/**/startup.test.ts'],
  testTimeout: 15000,
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/startupEnvVars.js'],
};


created the startupEnvVars.js file with the env variables

process.env.HOST = 'localhost';
process.env.DATABASE = 'my_db';
process.env.USERNAME = 'my_admin';
process.env.PASSWORD = 'my_passwd123';


remove env variables and ensured that process.env is copied over to the new process.

describe('STARTUP: test', () => {
  let app: ChildProcess;
  const url = 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/';

  beforeAll(async () => {
    app = spawn('node', ['index.js'], {
      detached: true,
      stdio: 'inherit',
      shell: true,
      env: {
        ...process.env,
      },
    });

    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 8000);
    });
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    app.kill();
  });

  it('should return when calling /health', async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(url);

    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
  });
});

